# How to change comma separator columns into fixed-width spaces?

Tags: linux, shell, csv

Reformat sql insert data:

```
('1', 'admin', '^/admin/$', null,'Admin Console', 0,'admin.dashboard.Admin', null),
('1-2',  'admin', '^/admin/aggregates/$', 1,'Host Aggregates', 0,'admin.aggregates.panel.Aggregates', null),
('1-2-1',  'admin', null, '1-2','Host Aggregates', 1,null, null),
```

to this:

```
('1',     'admin', '^/admin/$',            null,  'Admin Console',   0, 'admin.dashboard.Admin',             null),
('1-2',   'admin', '^/admin/aggregates/$', 1,     'Host Aggregates', 0, 'admin.aggregates.panel.Aggregates', null),
('1-2-1', 'admin', null,                   '1-2', 'Host Aggregates', 1, null,                                null),
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach that just reads the csv, and formats it as a table.  It uses powershell:

PS>  import-csv myinput.csv | format-table

This doesn't change the CSV file itself.  It just gives you a readable copy.  If you want to put the readable copy in another file, do this:

PS>  import-csv myinput.csv | format-table  > mycopy.txt

Note:  the real prompt isn't PS>. I just wrote it that way to save space.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an ASCII character that will never appear in your data? 
Perhaps `@`, `%` or `~`? 
If so, use that character as follows:

```
sed 's/, */,@/g' your_file | column -s'@' -t
```

The `sed` command separates your columns by `@` characters,
removing spaces between columns (but leaving the commas), like this:

```
('1',@'admin',@'^/admin/$',@null,@'Admin Console',@0,@'admin.dashboard.Admin',@null),@
('1-2',@'admin',@'^/admin/aggregates/$',@1,@'Host Aggregates',@0,@'admin.aggregates.panel.Aggregates',@null),@
('1-2-1',@'admin',@null,@'1-2',@'Host Aggregates',@1,@null,@null),@
```

The `column` command then separates the columns,
using `@` as the column separator (`-s'@'`),
and formats the data as a table (`-t`).